# Reading pseudo columns _FILE_NAME is not free in BigQuery contrary to the documentation

Tags: google-bigquery

as per the documentation , see here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing ,

Reading pseudo columns  You are not charged for querying the contents of the following pseudo columns:

_FILE_NAME — Used when querying tables based on external data sources

I run this Query and it did billed me 31 MB

```
SELECT _FILE_NAME as f FROM `xxxxxxx.yyyyyyy.scadaexternaltable`
```

what I am doing wrong ?

thanks

Comment: so the "second issue" is obvious - meantime please clarify - what was the charge amount?

Comment: 31 MB charged , I thought it should be free :), maybe I was dreaming

Comment: damn it of course the second issue is obvious :)

Comment: by chance - was it just 3 distinct file names in the output?

Comment: no, when I run SELECT distinct _FILE_NAME as f  I get 2045 , which is as expected, my bucket get new file every 5 minutes

Comment: interesting... good question! not sure if it belong here or for support. anyway upvoting it :o)

Comment: i will delete the second issue because as you said it is obvious

Comment: obviously. make sense :o)